# I want to build function that stops the playing song when I press the button to start another one

Tags: javascript, html

I've made it so you can give the function a variable which decides which song is going to be played (this code is used for multiple buttons which redirect to multiple songs).

The problem is, if I press one button and then another afterwards - two songs are playing at the same time. The question now is how do I implement that all the songs are paused before the selected one is played.

I thought of creating an array via jQuery and applying .stop to the array but that doesn't seem to work.

Code:

```
function aud_play_pause(n) {
    var myAudio = document.getElementById("Audio" + n);
    var taskArray = new Array();

    $('audio[id^="Audio"]').each(function() {
       taskArray.push($(this).val());
    });

    if (myAudio.paused) {
        taskArray.pause();
        myAudio.play();
    } else {
        myAudio.pause();
    }
}
```

Here's my snippet :

(the mp3 files are not included - that's why it throws an error it works though, I prom :D)

```js
function aud_play_pause(n) {
  var myAudio = document.getElementById("Audio" + n);
  var taskArray = new Array();

  $('audio[id^="Audio"]').each(function() {
    taskArray.push($(this).val());
  });

  if (myAudio.paused) {
    taskArray.pause();
    myAudio.play();
  } else {
    myAudio.pause();
  }
}
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
 .btn {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  background-color: #4a4a4a;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 42px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 3px;
  height: 3em;
  width: 22em;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.btn:hover,
.btn:focus,
.btn:active {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-4px);
  transform: translateY(-4px);
  background-color: #CF4647;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Handy Page</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="DragOn.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="code.js"></script>
</head>

<body bgcolor=#000000>
  <button class="btn" type="button" onclick="aud_play_pause(1)">Delax</button>
  <button class="btn" type="button" onclick="aud_play_pause(2)">Daft Punk</button>
  <button class="btn" type="button" onclick="aud_play_pause(3)">8-bit</button>
  <button class="btn" type="button" onclick="aud_play_pause(4)">Godwolf</button>
  <button class="btn" type="button" onclick="aud_play_pause(5)">Bounce</button>
  <audio class="music" id="Audio5" src="Orkestrated and Fries & Shine ft. Big Nab - Melbourne Bounce (Deorro Remix).mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 Audio element.
  </audio>
  <audio class="music" id="Audio4" src="Godwolf - Love Is A Battlefield.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 Audio element.
  </audio>
  <audio class="music" id="Audio3" src="unreal superheroe.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 Audio element.
  </audio>
  <audio class="music" id="Audio2" src="Daft Punk - Harder Better Faster Stronger RMX.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 Audio element.
  </audio>
  <audio id="Audio1" source src="Delax - Drop You Like.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 Audio element.
  </audio>
```

I'm extremely new to coding (since yesterday).

So either the answer is so obvious that no one would dare to ask it or just nobody has asked it yet (because I couldn't find anything on the internet).

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Arrays don't have a `.pause()` method, so you'd get an error on the line that says `taskArray.pause()`.

What you could do instead is loop through the items and pause them directly rather than using an array:

```
function aud_play_pause(n) {
  var myAudio = document.getElementById("Audio" + n);

  if (myAudio.paused) {
    $('audio[id^="Audio"]').not(myAudio).each(function() {
      this.pause();
    });
    myAudio.play();
  } else {
    myAudio.pause();
  }
}
```

(Note also that your use of `$(this).val()` in the `.each()` loop doesn't make sense because the `<audio>` elements don't have a `value`.)

Answer (score 0):

Since I see you are using jQuery you can do:

```
$('#Audio1')[0].play()
```

From my own experience jQuery doesn't provide a play() function, so you need to call play() on the real audio object, which is what the above code does (index is '0', since the selector should return a result with one entry). If you want pause all, turn something like:

```
$('audio').forEach(function (entry) {
    entry.pause();
})
```

Also, the html should be something of the form:

```
<audio id="Audio1">
    <source src="myfile.mp3">
</audio>
```

BTW as note style, JS convention suggests function names should be in camel case.

Also, for more on selectors (the text between `$(...)` ) see: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/